Price Update Webhook for tiered prices in Stripe - no webhook being triggered
I am currently setting up stripe webhooks for my application.
I am having an issue for price updates for prices that are tiered. Currently if I update the price of a tier then no webhook gets triggered for this event.
My webhooks for everything else are working fine, for instance for a price that is just a flat rate, when I update the price the webhook gets triggered.
I have tried to find information on this in the documentation but cannot find anything explicitly referencing this. Does stripe just not emit events for updates in pricing tiers?
I've looked at the documentation and have working test implementation for all the other web hooks relevant for my app.
Please see below for my code:
stripeWebhookRoute.mjs:
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser"
import stripePackage from 'stripe'
import { handleStripeWebhooks } from "../services/stripeServices/handleWebhooks.mjs";
const stripe = stripePackage(process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY);
const router = express.Router();




router.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), async (req, res) => {
    
    
    let event;
    
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    const webHookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_KEY;
   
    try {

        if (webHookSecret) {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, webHookSecret);
        } 
    


    } catch (error) {

        console.error('⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.', error.message);
        return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${error.message}`);

    }
    
     // Acknowledge receipt of the event right away
    res.status(200).json({ received: true });

    handleStripeWebhooks(event);
    
})





export default router; 


my handleWebHook.mjs file
import { handlePriceUpdate } from "./pricing/handlePricingUpdate.mjs";


/**
 * 
 * @param {*} event a stripe event
 * Receives a stripe webhook event and triggers execution logic. 
 */
export const handleStripeWebhooks = async(event) => {
   
    switch (event.type) {
        case 'price.updated':
            console.log("Price updated");
            handlePriceUpdate(event);
            break;
    
        default:
            console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
    }
}


How are you updating the prices that are tiered? Could you share the example code?

Hi there, thanks for your response @yuting I have updated the post to include code

Your code only showed how price.updated event is handled, but it didn't mentioned how you updated the tiered price. Update Prices API doesn't support updating the amount and currency. What have you tried to update on a tiered price?

Hi sorry, at the moment I have just been changing the price in the stripe dashboard - not programatically.

Not sending price.updated event is expected for changing the amount on tier prices since tiers property is not included in the Price object by default.
tiers is an expandable field, i.e. it will only be available upon requesting additional information of this specific property.
For any expandable property which isn't included in the object by default, no update event will be sent.

Hi there, thank you very much for answering this. Understood
